# Detect design mode in Word

Tags: office-js, word-addins

I'm building an Office-AddIn in a Angular/Typescript setting that lets users add bindings from a Web API.

Is it possible to detect if a Word-document is in Design Mode? I want to prevent my users from accidentally clearing or setting placeholder text of Content Controls using the AddIn functionality to update all bindings.